# Can OneNote file be viewed inside my application?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, office365, onenote

I want to see OneNote file inside my windows store application. Is it possible? Does OneNote api facilitate it? Is there any OneNote viewer that can be integrated for custom made Windows Store apps?

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2015 there is no embeddable viewer.

The OneNote team is working on an embedding solution which should be usable for both web and native app embedded scenarios.  The uservoice request is here https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis/suggestions/5909975-allow-live-onenote-pages-to-be-embedded-on-a-websi

Following the OneNote API [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev) is the best way to hear announcements in this space.